# extending jquery (multiple extends) with require.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, extending

I'm in the process of converting some old website code to utilize AMD and on-demand loading where possible.  One of the things I ran across is that the site uses an older version of jquery on some pages (I've figured out how to configure this prior to the code being refactored and tested with a newer one) but the original developers also added a number of extensions to jquery for some of the forms.

I'll eventually want to refactor these as well, but since it is extending jquery with a number of new helper functions, I'm wondering how to configure require.js to make sure these extensions are loaded.  Worst care scenario, I can append this onto the jquery.js but I'd prefer not to do that a someone may not be aware they are there and replace jquery itself breaking any code depending on those extension.

the extends block looks like:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    vshow: function(speed,callback) { /* ... */ },
    vhide: function(speed,callback) {  /* ... */  },
    vshowif: function(b) {  /* ... */  },
    showif: function(b) {  /* ... */  },
    selected: function(i) {  /* ... */  },
    addOptions: function(a,f,p) { /* ... */  },
    setOptions: function(a,f,p) {  /* ... */  },
    validateForm: function(f) {  /* ... */  },
    lt: function(n) {  /* ... */  },
    gt: function(n) {  /* ... */  }
});
```

I know I could also break them up into multiple jquery.function.js files but some of them are only a few lines.  I'm wondering if there is a way or what the proper way is to make sure these are loaded after jquery whenever jquery is used?

Answer (score 0):

I have a temporary fix in place that is based on a couple of factors about the code I'm upgrading, but it's not an ideal solution. (I imagine the ultimate solution is going to be to separate the custom extensions into separate, individual plugin files and include them in the dependency lists where they are needed)

One of the issues I'm dealing with is this is an old code base. I don't have the time at the moment to fully upgrade/update all of the libraries and test them thoroughly as the current project is a priority. But the version of jquery being used by the existing code is an old version that probably isn't even fully AMD.
The functionality my new code is using is rather basic (simple ajax calls mostly) and works with both the new and the old versions. I can't be certain about the legacy code usages or how these extensions work. Thus the using the old jquery presents an easier for-now solution.

As a result, when I tell require.js to load the 'old' jquery to keep the compatibility with the legacy code, it is essentially re-loading jquery and clobbering the extended functions used by the original form, causing it to fail silently when the extended functions aren't defined.

I've gotten around this for the time being by putting the above extends block inside of it's own .js file I've called jquery-extended.js. I then add a shim configuration for:

```
    "jquery.extended" : {
        "deps" : ['jquery'],
        "exports" : "$"
    },
```

Then any of my current libs/modules that require jquery, I instead change their dependency to jquery.extended instead of just jquery and it seems to at least allow the code to work.

But if there are any other suggestions on handling this, I would be curious to hear about them.